# Jquery Mobile div Data role Panel not getting displayed propely

Tags: jquery-mobile

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/13/

When you run this fiddle

1. Click on the square box on the right side of the locations (A Panel is getting displayed and its working fine)

The issue is that .

When you click on the Delivery and click on the square box  on the right side of the locations  (The Panel gets displayed but its not working properly (not getting closed and not aligned properly))

Could you please let me know how to fix this ??

To solve the i tried calling the same above panel that is rightpanel when clicked on the Locations square box on the right side , but this did not solve the issue .

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href=#rightpanel_2]', function(event) {
        $("a[href=#rightpanel]").trigger("click");
    });
```

could you please let me kno how to resolve the issue ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could anybody please let me know how to fix this issue ??

Comment: Is the displaylabels div supposed to be a page or a popup or should it replace content of current page?

Comment: Thanks for responding  , anything is fine for me if it serves my requirement .

Comment: I mean when the user is in displaylabels and clicks on the square button , it should behave exactly as its behaving in the starting screen .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jWaEv/15/  Make it another page and make sure to close your DIVs properly